# User specific database in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently working on an inventory management software in Node js and MongoDB. I am pretty new to MongoDB, having worked in Oracle and MySQL for most of my projects.

Is it possible to create a separate database schema for every client who uses my software, with each client having access only to his copy of the database schema and collections?

The equivalent of selecting data in Oracle database would be
Select * from User1.table,
Select * from User2.table etc

Also, if it were possible, how would it be implemented using a node js mongo db client like mongoose?

I looked at MongoDB documentation, but it talks mainly about adding users to a database for authorization.

I apologize if it seems like a silly question, but id appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting to invest a lot of time in the development of your project, check out other possible approaches to the scenario that you are trying to build.

I did a quick search on SO and found some additional threads with similar scenarios:

- [MongoDB Database vs. Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937806/mongodb-database-vs-collection)
- [MongoDB Web App - Database per User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582683/mongodb-web-app-database-per-user)
- [Additional info about mongoose database creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459286/how-to-create-a-new-db-in-mongoose)

Whenever you call the `connect` method on the `mongoose` object, you are either connecting to an existing database or you are creating it in case it doesn't already exist.

You could have a function that allows you to pass in a name argument with the name and create databases programmatically:

```
function createDatabase(name) {
    var conn_string = 'mongodb://localhost/';

    if (typeof name == 'string') {
        conn_string += name;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

    mongoose.connect(conn_string);  
}
```

Also, be aware that a database will be created when you first insert a record in a collection of that particular database.

It is not sufficient to only connect to the database, you also have to insert a record.

As per my previous example, you could also pass a schema parameter to the function, tailored to each user's profile and fire an insert statement after you connect to that database.